textvalidating Response Text in form via Google Apps Script
I have a form of Some Question to our subscriber in .setHelpText I want to show Name of Subscriber Depent of Registration Code in Form Field
The Register Code and Name Are Save in Google Sheet Colum A  Reg.Code and in  Colum B Name
What i have Done
function setPattern(e) {
  // Get the firm item
  const form = FormApp.openById('FormID')
  const item = form.getItemById('ItemID').asTextItem()

  // Get the list of values
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SheetID')
  const psheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('subscriber')
  const values = psheet.getRange(1, 1, psheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat()
  const match = psheet.getRange(1, 2, psheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat()
  //var idRange = psheet.getRange(1, 1, psheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  
  /** // iterate over all your IDs
  for(i=0;i<idRange.length;i++){
    // if one ID is the same as the incoming one from the form response
    if(idRange[i] == values){
      // get its value to the form
      psheet.getRange(i+1, 2);
    }
  } **/
 const pattern = `^(${values.map(_escapeRegex).join('|')})$`
  var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText(match+ " Is this your name?")
  .requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(pattern)
  .build();
  item.setValidation(validation);
  Logger.log(match)
}

Its show all Row of Colum B List but i just want to show the value of pattern that is enter in Textinput.
Sample Data
+------+------------------------+
| 1014 | Mohamed Touzani        |
+------+------------------------+
| 3052 | Yildiz Satrel          |
+------+------------------------+
| 3057 | Hind Abou Ridouane     |
+------+------------------------+
| 3076 | Adil Khan              |
+------+------------------------+
| 3068 | Maram Ibrahim          |
+------+------------------------+
| 3075 | Banaz Elias Khider     |
+------+------------------------+
| 3077 | Manal Kasmi Jai        |
+------+------------------------+
| 3078 | Narmin Al-hakari       |
+------+------------------------+
| 3082 | Maroua Chelhi Tadlaoui |
+------+------------------------+
| 1019 | Rainayul Hasnat        |
+------+------------------------+
| 3074 | Lorena Marsavela       |
+------+------------------------+
| 3067 | Mohammed Moosa Raufi   |
+------+------------------------+
| 3086 | Mohamed Idris Lhouty   |
+------+------------------------+
| 1020 | Oussama Banequi        |
+------+------------------------+
| 3087 | Demirdas Muhammed-Ali  |
+------+------------------------+
| 3088 | Chtioui Hafssa         |
+------+------------------------+


Kindly share a minimal, reproducible example—no sensitive data with your desired output—that the community can use to replicate and see what you'd like to do.

You may use Tables to create one, with tools like Table to Markdown to help you easily copy and paste the data from the spreadsheet into the question, and as a last resort (not recommended since access may be revoked after the question has been answered), you can also Make an anonymous sample document.

@Saddles Table sample add in my post hope this help

If I understand this correctly, the goal is to show the name of a subscriber/respondent by doing a real-time update to/from a Google Sheet. The question is silent on how the function is triggered but, possibly, it is an installable onFormSubmit. If this is correct, then the goal cannot be achieved. 1) Google Forms does not support any real-time update to/from Google Sheets. 2) onFormSubmit is triggered when the respondent submits the relevant form. It does not enable the form to be updated while the respondent is still completing the form.

@Tedinoz the goal is to do real time update with  form textvalidation and app script index match and to show the value of ColumB what i want is  to get the match result of input itemtext or the pattern as match. The script search in live update the value of text input in sheet and give the helptext if the match fund or not.

the goal is to do real time update Thanks for the clarification. As I mentioned, Google Forms does not include the ability to do any kind "real-time update". Lots of people would like this feature so you could consider lodging a feature request.

@Tedinoz is correct. This Stack Overflow post is one of many that's similar to this, and I'm not sure if this'll help you out, @John Kater, but I saw Dynamic Fields - Update Forms questions in Google Workspace Marketplace. I'm not affiliated with that and am not promoting it. However, I think it could help you out.
